# How to open a folder in a certain folder by using an input [C++]

Tags: c++

im trying to open a folder which I do use as a database and in the inside there should be even more folders that contain various text files.
So here's the question, how do I add two chars together so I can create a folder inside my desired folder from my input?

```
void registracija() {
system("cls");
char usr_temp;
cout << "________________________REGISTRACIJA________________________" << endl;
cout << "REGISTRACIJA: NORINT UZSIREGISTRUOTI, JUMS REIKES SUGALVOTI" << endl;
cout << "REGISTRACIJA: SLAPYVARDI, SLAPTAZODI BEI KLAUSIMA" << endl;
cout << "REGISTRACIJA: KURIS BUS NAUDOJAMAS GRAZINTI PAMIRSTAM SLAPTAZODZIUI!" << endl;
cout << "NORIMAS SLAPYVARDIS: ";
cin >> usr_temp;
const char temp = usr_temp;
char dirname1[] = "Vartotojai/" + usr_temp;
char *dirname = dirname1;
int check = _mkdir(dirname);
if (!check) {
    cout << "TESIAME REGISTRACIJA";
}
else {
    cout << "REGISTRACIJA: TOKS SLAPYVARDIS JAU YRA! REGISTRUOKITES IS NAUJO!";
    system("pause>nul");
}
```

}

Faults I get:

```
Se cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char []'  ConsoleApplication1
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of cstring. cstrings can't be concatenated with `operator+`. You need `strcat` for cstrings.

Comment: See also `std::ostringstream`, which you can use to build filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::string` instead of cstring. cstrings can't be concatenated with `operator+`. You need `std::strcat` for cstrings. You also need to reassign memory if you want to use cstrings. It's much easier with `std::string`

Change

```
char usr_temp;

char dirname1[] = "Vartotojai/" + usr_temp;
char *dirname = dirname1;
```

to

```
std::string usr_tmp;

std::string dirname1("Vartotojai/");
dirname1 += usr_temp;
const char *dirname = dirname1.c_str();
```

Remove the line with char_temp. You have to include `string`. `std::string` is a container for characters. You can easily append new characters without managing memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seem to be working, but instead it creates a folder of only first letter of input, what's could be wrong?

Comment: usr_tmp is a char. You are reading  only the first char. Use string for usr_tmp

Comment: Well that's logical:D Thank you, Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this.

```
 string dirname1 = "Vartotojai/" + string(1,usr_temp);
 char *dirname = (char*)dirname1.c_str();
// char *dirname = const_cast<char*>(dirname1.c_str());
```

As you have tagged it C++, use string type instead of char array and char pointer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It seem to work aswell, like the given solution earlier, but im facing the same problem that it creates a folder with only the first letter, should I use cycle to create a new string out of the chars or is there any other solutions?

Comment: Show us _mkdir method

Comment: It's like that:                                                                                                                        int check = _mkdir(dirname);
 if (!check) {
  cout << "TESIAME REGISTRACIJA";
 }
 else {
  cout << "REGISTRACIJA: TOKS SLAPYVARDIS JAU YRA! REGISTRUOKITES IS NAUJO!";
  system("pause>nul");
 }

Comment: @RoshanMehta: [_mkdir](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkdir-wmkdir?view=vs-2017) is part of visual c compiler